# How to use same XMPP connection through out the app

Tags: android, android-intent, connection, xmpp, smack

I am working on a Chat Application using `XMPP` with `asmack`. At startup `Activity` I want to make `XMPP` connection then use it in the different activities. But I have no idea how to do this. I searched a lot about it but couldn't find any desired solution. Please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the `Connection` member static and choose a access level modifier keyword that allows other Activities access that member.

But, you usually don't want to have the `Connection` be handled within an Activity, but within an class that extends `Service`. There are a bunch of open source apps out there that use aSmack, have a look at their source.

Comment: i have created the connection in service but still got problem while retrieving it in activity.

Comment: As I said, you could make the Connection static and visible for the Activity.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this class to set the connection and get it anywhere in other activity

```
public class XMPPLogic {

  private XMPPConnection connection = null;

  private static XMPPLogic instance = null;

  public synchronized static XMPPLogic getInstance() {
    if(instance==null){
      instance = new XMPPLogic();
    }
    return instance;
  }

  public void setConnection(XMPPConnection connection){
    this.connection = connection;
  }

  public XMPPConnection getConnection() {
    return this.connection;
  }

}
```

and set the connection like this..

```
XMPPLogic.getInstance().setConnection(connection);
```

and get connection like this..

```
connection = XMPPLogic.getInstance().getConnection();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use singleton design pattern or make a utility class and define xmpp connection as static and then you can use it in any activity.

for singleton do like this :

```
public class MyConnection{
private static MyConnection con;
private MyConnection(){

        //ToDo here

}
public static MyConnection getInstance()
{
    if (con == null)
   {
      MyConnection= new MyConnection();
   }
   return con;
   }

}
```

then in any activity you can access that object by typing `MyConnection.getInstance();`